# How to update array in mongodb using mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb

when i try to update it dose not throw back any error it goes OK but when i check my datebase nothing i their updated nothing is modified pls help

```
this is my db
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("56651f0e4905bd041cad0413"),
    "creator" : ObjectId("566299dd17990464160ae27a"),
    "content" : "this is my joke 2",
    "created" : ISODate("2015-12-07T05:54:22.858Z"),
    "__v" : 15,
    "comments" : [ 
        {
            "posteruserId" : "5665e6867185d87c1e71dbdc",
            "postedBy" : "lawrence nwoko",
            "postterscomment" : "good joke",
            "_id" : ObjectId("56660745f644c2501116acce")
        }, 
        {
            "posteruserId" : "5665e6867185d87c1e71dbdc",
            "postedBy" : "lawrence nwoko",
            "postterscomment" : "good joke",
            "_id" : ObjectId("56660b6d33c245c012104fdc")
        }
    ]
}
```

this is my schema

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var JokesSchema = new Schema({
    creator: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'},
    content:  String,
    created:{type:Date, default: Date.now},
    comments: [{
        text: String,
        postedBy: String,
        posteruserId :String,
        date: String,
        postterscomment:String
    }]
})
module.exports = mongoose.model('Jokes_db', JokesSchema)
```

here i my post funtion
    api.post('/update', function(req, res) {

```
//        Joke.findById("56651f0e4905bd041cad0413", function (err, meeting) {
            Joke.update({_id: "5665e6867185d87c1e71dbdc", 'comments._id' : "56660745f644c2501116acce"},
                {'$set': {
                    'comments.$.postterscomment': "working"
                }},

                function(err, numAffected) {
                    if(err){
                        console.log(err)
                    }else{
                        res.json(numAffected)
                    }
                }
            );
        });
```

Comment: Are you sure your schema is correct here? if not then post the defined schema. Mainly noting here that the `_id` used for the main document in the `.update()` does not match the document shown here though. So if this is the document you expect to update then the `_id` value is wrong. So `"5665e6867185d87c1e71dbdc"` appears to be the `comments.postuserId` value rather than `"56651f0e4905bd041cad0413"` which is actually the document `_id` field.

Comment: i just added my mongoose Schema please take a look at it

Comment: But were you paying attention to the wrong `_id` value being used as mentioned as well? That would seem to be the problem here.

Comment: i have tried Switching the id_ but still nothing, where cloud the problem be this is the respond i get from the server
{
  "ok": 1,
  "nModified": 0,
  "n": 0
}

Comment: { [MongoError: The field 'comments.0.postterscomment' must be an array but is of type String in document {_id: ObjectId('56651f0e4905bd041cad0413')}]
  name: 'MongoError',
  message: 'The field \'comments.0.postterscomment\' must be an array but is of type String in document {_id: ObjectId(\'56651f0e4905bd041cad0413\')}',
  driver: true,
  index: 0,
  code: 16837,
  errmsg: 'The field \'comments.0.postterscomment\' must be an array but is of type String in document {_id: ObjectId(\'56651f0e4905bd041cad0413\')}' }

Comment: i modifier my quarry like this     {_id:'56651f0e4905bd041cad0413', 'comments._id' :'56660745f644c2501116acce'}, This was the erro i got

Answer (score 0):

It has been three days of trying to fix this problem but by his grace I have done it without help the problem user that I was not using the right id to make the query thanks for your help guys I hope this helps another user

```
 api.post('/editecomments', function(req, res) {
        Joke.update({_id: "56651f0e4905bd041cad0413", 'comments._id' : "56660745f644c2501116acce"},
            {'$set': {'comments.$.postterscomment': 'working'}},

            function(err, numAffected) {
                if(err){
                    console.log(err)
                }else{
                    res.json(numAffected)
                }
            }
        );
    });
```